# Count min max length in numbers without space in jquery validate js

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I am using jquery validate js to validate my number field.

```
phone: {
    required: true,
    minlength: 10,
    maxlength: 10,
    numero:true,
},
```

**numero** is custom validator method that allows numbers with space. Now it is counting that space as well. How to avoid and make things work with min and max length of phone number only counting numbers?

Comment: can you show your full html code <input style="padding: 7px;" maxlength="10" size="50" id="txtbox" type="text">

Answer (score 1):

i would say since its a phone number change input type text to input type number or tel   tel will be best ... then you dont need to worry about the white spaces